# Under FAA rules, can a private pilot act as PIC in aircraft furnished by someone else if they're not otherwise compensated?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, ppl, compensation

Let's say I'm visiting a friend who happens to own an airplane, and I happen to be a private pilot holding a valid FAA PPL, as well as being familiar with the make and model my friend owns. Suppose my friend says "I'll show you around the avionics, and if you want to take her for a ride around the area, feel free. She's topped up on fuel, so you don't have to worry about it". Would it be legal for me to take them up on the offer if:

1. I were to fly alone, and not get compensated in any way, but also not bear any expenses related to the flight?

   1. As above, but the friend also says "oh and by the way, I have a fuel card stashed in the cockpit, you can use it to refuel if you need to"
2. I were to take my wife and two friends, who are also visiting, as passengers?

   1. As above, but again with fuel card
3. I were to act as PIC for a volunteer flight transporting sick patients, given that I receive no compensation for the flying, but my friend is furnishing the plane and the fuel onboard. They'd fly it themselves, but their IFR rating is not current and mine is

   1. As above, but I also refuel the plane using their fuel card
   2. As above, but the plane is provided by the organisation coordinating the flights, rather than my friend

I understand the basic limitations of the private pilot certificate, and that there's a broad prohibition on receiving any compensation for the carriage of passengers of cargo, including non-monetary compensation such as "building flying time". I am not, however, sufficiently versed in all the relevant interpretations to establish whether the above examples fall under the exemptions carved out for bona-fide common interest or volunteer flights.

**Edit** to clarify a point alluded to, but not explicitly addressed in one of the answers: my friend is not a business partner of mine, nor do I expect ever to do business with them. The intent of this (hypothetical) situation is that they are letting me fly their plane for fun, just as they could let me take their 700HP Dodge Charger Hellcat for a ride.

**Edit 2**: to make the unstated assumption explicit, I'm assuming that hours will be logged for those flights. The FAA has made it reasonably clear in the past that if hours are not logged, their compensatory aspect vanishes and thus renders many otherwise prohibited flights legal.

Comment: @757toga: I don't know that they all do though. At least in example 1, the friend is simply letting me take their plane for a funride, and doesn't care if I go, or when or where to. They get no benefit from it, and are not directingmy actions a the PIC, so I'm not providing any air carriage service for compensation or hire. That is my understanding of the rules at least, but I'd like to have a more solid argument that either confirms or disproves my take.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/96239

Comment: how is one allowed to fly a plane at all if they're not allowed to fly a plane in exchange for having recorded time spent flying a plane?

Comment: @user253751 In the situations described in the OP's question "accumulating flight time," for which the OP (a private pilot subject to the limitations specified in FAR 61.113) pays nothing, would be considered "compensation," as noted in the FAA Interpretation linked/shown below. That is my opinion of how the regulation and Interpretation apply.

Comment: @757toga so how can one possibly be allowed to fly a plane with a PPL?

Comment: @user253751 In the situations described in the OP's question he would have to pay for the fuel. Otherwise he is receiving "compensation" (which is contrary to FAR 61.113) by accumulating flight time for free. Read the linked FAA interpretation below. Perhaps you would arrive at a different conclusion.

Comment: There is a lot of bad info here. @DJClayworth has the best approach, although I don't know that he has the right answer. Yes, flight time *could* be considered compensation, but it is not at all *always* considered compensation. I periodically fly a friend's plane, to make sure it doesn't sit for extended periods of time. Is someone seriously making the claim that my time is so worthless that when I spend it to help a friend out *he* is compensating *me*? That my life, which was not at risk on the ground, is so worthless that a few minutes of flight is compensation?

Comment: @KennSebesta: Flight time *is* of value, and thus might be compensation. The FAA has made it abundantly clear, and specifically said that an ATPL rated pilot, with nothing they could be building time towards, is still receiving compensation when they get free flight time under their PPL privileges. Your situation is very close to #1 above, but whether it's for compensation or hire doesn't hinge on whether time is something of value, we already know it is. If anyone's common sense or intuition clashes with FAA's interpretation, then FAA's intepretation wins when legality is concerned. Sorry.

Comment: @mathrick to the contrary, read the FAA's Legal Interpretation: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/1990/Lincoln-Soaring%20Society%20of%20America_1990_Legal_Interpretation.pdf. The FAA counsel specifically says, "It could be argued that the accumulation of flight time is not always of value to the pilot involved". Thus, "*whether it's for compensation or hire doesn't hinge on whether time is something of value, we already know it is.*" is not correct, as from the FAA we know the opposite.

Comment: @KennSebesta: if you don't log time, then obviously you're not being compensated through building free time. Also, that counsel is no longer relevant, since [61.113(g)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.113(g)) now specifically exempts glider towing.

Comment: @KennSebesta: also, *the very next sentence in that counsel* says: "The FAA does not consider it appropriate to enter into a case-by-case analysis to determine whether the logging of time is of value to a particular pilot, or what the pilot's motives or intentions are on each flight"

Comment: @mathrick Exactly! So to the discussion at hand, there is not a *de facto* assumption that flight time = value. With the FAA legal interpretation in mind, we might argue that there is insufficient clarity in the OQ. We can definitely make a lot of hay out of the fact that the FAA has wedged itself into the corner in such a way that it actively discourages pilots to log hours, but for the purposes of this question it is a very clear and shining example of how the FAA views "value": if you're doing it as a favor to a friend or associate, e.g. towing, then only the logging *may* have value.

Comment: @KennSebesta: OK, yes, I guess you got me there. It was an unstated assumption in my question that I want to log hours for those flights. It is implicitly there, in that I asked about the compensatory value of building time, but I didn't make it explicit. Will edit to reflect that.

Comment: @mathrick thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not sure anyone short of the FSDO can answer your question. It's bonkers that the act of flying can be illegal if I enjoy it but perfectly legal if I moan and groan about it. Maybe that's why we pilots are so curmudgeonly!

Comment: **FAA:**  "*The FAA does not consider it appropriate to enter into a case-by-case analysis to determine whether the logging of time is of value to a particular pilot, or what the pilot's motives or intentions are on each flight.*"

Comment: **Also FAA:**  "*We note that whether a private pilot is receiving something of value in exchange for acting as pilot in command is determined on a case-by-case basis and depends greatly on the purpose and objective of the flight*"

Comment: The only real answer to this question is "*it depends*"...  On that basis I'm deleting my earlier attempt to answer this and punting.

Comment: @MichaelHall You have a good point.  This is a question that is difficult to clearly answer without accepting that there are various legitimate points of view that can't really be resolved in a fashion that everyone agrees with.  I'm going to delete my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

For something to be "compensation," *both* sides must receive something of value. It's a "if you do X, I'll give you Y" kind of affair. "I'll give you Y unconditionally" is a "gift," not compensation. You are clearly receiving something of value in every case, so the question is if the owner is receiving something in return.

Cases 1 and 2 are essentially a short-term aircraft lease (albeit at sweetheart rates), and are definitely legal as long as the gift is truly unconditional. That said, you can expect the FAA and NTSB to be very skeptical of large unconditional gifts. Particular in case 2, if the two friends are also friends of the owner, it's easy to paint this as "the owner paid you to take their friends up for a flight."

Case 3 is definitely illegal. "If you act as PIC of this charity flight, I'll give you free flight time" is exactly the sort of quid pro quo that makes this illegal compensation instead of a gift.

All that said, this is all kind of a moot point. If the FAA decides to take action, you've basically already lost. While you might win the eventual NTSB appeal, you'll still have sunk tons of time and money into defending yourself.

If a bona fide friend is giving you a bona fide gift of flying their airplane, there's no reason the FAA should ever hear about it.

Answer (score -1):

Let's go back to basics and read the actual law.

> No person who holds a private pilot certificate may act as pilot in command of an aircraft that is carrying passengers or property **for** compensation or hire; nor may that person, **for** compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft.

In legal terms "compensation" means that a person is doing something for someone else ("work" or "service" in legal terms), and in return receiving something of value - a payment. See this [legal definition](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/compensation). It doesn't mean gifts. Real gifts are just gifts, and are not compensation, because there is no work or service involved.

When talking about compensation people love to quote this FAA opinion:
[image: Screenshot of FAA opinion]

The specific quote is:

> compensation is the receipt of anything of value. Reimbursement of
> expenses [...] accumulation of flight time and goodwill in the form of
> expected future economic benefit could be considered compensation.

This has led some people to suggest that any time as pilot is given something, such as free flight time or the loan of an aircraft, that **automatically and always** is considered compensation.

However the opinion doesn't say that. It says these things **could be** considered compensation - not they **are** or **must be** compensation.

One of the things deciding if flight time will be considered compensation is whether it satisfies the legal definition of compensation given above.  A gift doesn't satisfy it. It's safe to say the FAA knows that and that's one of the reasons they write "could be" in their opinion. The questions was about what *forms* of payment could be considered compensation, and they are answering with examples of things that *could be* compensation if they satisfy the legal definition.

As people have seen, the FAA takes a very wide view of what constitutes "a service", and what constitutes "compensation". Taking a passenger for a pleasure flight is a "service", and as we have seen receiving flying hours free or at a reduced rate can be a form of payment. But there have to be both the service and the payment for it to be considered "compensation". If that were not the case then gifting a pilot with an hour of flying time for his birthday would be illegal.

The FAA also takes a wide view of what a "service" is. Carrying passengers, even for a pleasure flight, is a service, and you cannot be compensated for it, even with reduced rate flights.  This is what leads to the strict rules on expense sharing. It should also be said that attempts to hide the service and recompense are illegal. If the friend "gifted" you flying time and you also "happened" to use it to take something of his somewhere, the courts would see through that as a pretence and rule it illegal.

Based on this, the friend allowing you to use his aircraft is a gift and not "compensation". You are not performing any service for him. The first situation is completely legal, as long as the gift is not conditional on you doing anything for him as a pilot. The second is also legal as long under the same conditions, provided that the people you take as passenger don't have a connection with the aircraft owner that makes this a transaction. Making a service "under the table" also doesn't change the legality, and you can't disguise a trade by saying "He gifted me the use of his plane and I then gifted him my services to fly him somewhere.". That's not going to believed by courts or the FAA.

The third situation is more complex. You are performing a service, but not for the aircraft owner. Fortunately this is a fairly common scenario and the FAA certainly has guidance on it.

It's worth noting that if the gifting of flight time without a service in return were illegal then that would make many things illegal that happen all the time. For example, most of my flight training was paid for by someone else - they gifted me that flight time. That commonly and openly occurs. But if all gifts are considered compensation then that would be illegal. It isn't illegal because I have performed no service that makes it "compensation".

Comment: Note that JimInTexas has the right answer also. I am writing this additional one because of the huge levels of misunderstanding around the law here.

Comment: Worth reading: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/96247/20394. The FAA specifically allows flying, so long as it's not logged. Ergo, flying for free is not *de facto* compensation.

Comment: Highlighting the different opinions on "compensation," @KennSebesta in a comment below the OP's question indicates that he periodically flies a friend's airplane so it doesn't sit for extended periods. If his friend pays for the fuel then Kenn is presumably  providing a "service" and accumulating flight time (certainly with the friend's knowledge or because the friend has requested that it be flown periodically) would this not constitute "compensation" under your definition? I don't have an opinion one way or the other, but some circumstances can be viewed differently by different people.

Comment: In my opinion that would be providing a service and thus not technically legal if his friend pays costs.

Comment: That's an interesting take. I think you're right that I'm certainly providing a service, but it would be very hard to claim I'm getting just compensation, or anything approaching that. Either I'm working for free, or at such a reduced rate that the $10 in fuel burned is trivial compared to my costs in getting to the airport, getting the plane out, flying till the oil is warm, cleaning it off, and storing it.

Comment: It is worth noting that, on an incredibly strict interpretation *everything* is only done if the value to the person exceeds the cost. So in that case, it's impossible to do anything which isn't paid for in value. This is the same rationale as charging sales tax on all purchases, no matter how old or used the item is. And since the use tax is actually the rule of the land across the US, it is not trivial to dismiss that analogy. As a result, the *reductio ad absurdum* argument actually fails here, because in the *homo economicus* world no action is taken without greater compensation than cost.

Comment: @KennSebesta That's a (insanely) strict philosophical approach, and it's not true legally. The law recognizes that gifts do exist. It's also worth saying that all these interpretations are not binding. They are just the opinions of the FAA. Even if the FAA says "this is illegal" it's possible to go to court and argue that the FAA is wrong.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think we are in 100% agreement. I'm just pointing out that there is precedence for having this kind of insanely strict standard, and so that makes it harder to dismiss out of hand that "no one would ever enforce such a strict interpretation." So the FAA *could* theoretically go down that route, even though it has had the good sense not to.

Answer (score -2):

All of your scenarios are legal under Part 91, except 3)3, which the FSDO might not like.

If own an airplane I can let my friends fly it.

Period.

Specifically:

1. Your friend lets you use his fuel card.  So what?  Unless there is an **exchange** of something of value between you and him nobody cares who pays for the gas.
2. Nobody cares if you take a friend, assuming you are current and are not flying in **exchange** for something of value from the owner, and you and your pax have a common purpose.
3. As far as sub points 1 and 2, that's clearly within part 91.  For insurance and FAA purposes I'd recommend conducting this flight through a Public Benefit non-profit, such as Angel Flight.

Subpoint #3:  If a FSDO guy is having a bad day he or she might want to quibble with this flight.   For sure if the 'organization' providing the airplane is a for profit entity you'd be out of line, because now your free flying would be considered compensation in exchange for helping the organization make a buck.

If the 'organization' providing is a non-profit, such a flying missionaries organization, then IMHO I don't think it'd be a problem, but you better coordination this flight with your FSDO and insurance company.

Note, when I say **exchange** I mean the pilot who lent you his plane gains some kind of economic value as a result of your flight.

What the FAA defiantly does not want to see is aircraft commercial operators 'hiring' private pilots to fly persons or cargo for free as part of a business operation.  That's the big NO-NO.

For example, about 30 years I knew a kid who had recently earned is private ticket at a little dirt strip in central Texas.  The local mechanic had deal with some Canadians to buy and refurb light planes, and to ferry these airplanes to airports near the Canada-US border.

The mechanic asked my friend if he could do any of these delivery flights. Of course my friend jumped at this chance to fly big cross countries for free.

The mechanic paid all the expenses for these flights, but didn't pay the pilots anything.

Under current FAA policy these flights would be 'go directly to jail, we are throwing away the key'!

**Note to Mayor Pete and Captain Nolen:  This was over 30 years ago and the mechanic died years ago, as did my friend.**

Comment: Regarding #1 & 2, that "something of value" is flight time.  Reference the FAA interpretations quoted in 757toga's answer.  "nobody cares who pays for the gas" um, the FAA does.  61.113(c) is pretty clear:  "A private pilot may not pay less than the pro rata share of the operating expenses of a flight with passengers, provided the expenses involve only fuel, oil, airport expenditures, or rental fees."

Comment: This is the correct answer. The flight time is not "compensation" because the pilot is not performing a service to be compensated for. There cannot be 'compensation" without a service provided.

Comment: @MichaelHall  61.113(c) is talking about sharing expenses with passengers. But the aircraft owner is not a passenger.

Comment: @DJClayworth, if the owner is not a certificated pilot, and they are on board the aircraft, they are a passenger.

Comment: @MichaelHall In the question the owner is not on board the aircraft.

Comment: @DJClayworth, ok, forget (c) then. Read (a).  It says nothing about the pilot providing a service.

Comment: Yes, because that's a basic assumption of the law. It is acting as PIC **for** hire or compensation that is forbidden. If the pilot is not receiving "compensation" in the legal sense then he is not breaking the law.